# Why does maximizing Visual Studio 2010 trigger the Windows 7 Basic color scheme

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

In visual studio 2010 professional, when I maximize the window on a monitor that is 2048 x 1152, Windows 7 changes to the basic color theme (disables aero). Most of the time now I manually resize the window to be the full screen, just not actually maximized which gets around the problem, but is quite annoying.

Maximizing to one of my smaller 1680 x 1050 monitors on the same machine does not cause this problem.

[image]

Done quite a few searches with no results... Any ideas?

Comment: Unusual.  I'd guess that DWM is running out of memory.  This is a question for superuser.com

Comment: Yea, I had a hard time deciding whether I should post here or superuser.com, but ultimately decided SO is filled with people who use VS daily, and might have more luck finding somebody who had this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix disabling of Aero when VS2010 go full screen you need disable
**"Use hardware graphics acceleration if available"** in
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General

Comment: You are amazing! I knew someone would finally have the answer. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the blanket suggestion is to try upgrading your video drivers.

See this issue submitted to Microsoft Connect:
Resharper and XAML:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/567407/visual-studio-2010-switches-to-basic-color-scheme

And this post on MSDN:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/974a0645-53e2-47bf-9463-69b1119bffd3

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Updating video drivers was blindingly obvious, and I got excited for a moment... but no go. Tried windows update, then direct from nVidia, but the problem continues. Also checked your links, but I don't have resharper or other addons to remove from VS

Comment: Arrgh. Hopefully an answer will come up.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to run the Aero Troubleshooter. You should be able to get to it by clicking on the balloon and reading the help (there is a link to it there, search for "aero troubleshooter" if you don't find it right away) or by searching for aero in the control panel.

On my laptop the troubleshooter reported that it had changed "something" (god knows what) and then the problem disappeared... magic!

/AZ

Comment: So i re-enabled hardware acceleration (undoing the fix that currently works) to test this. It found that the Desktop Window Manager (DWM) was not running, and tried to re-enable it (which only worked if I ran the troubleshooter when Visual Studio was not maximized). So it didn't actually work as a solution, but it did let me know that Visual Studio is making DWM close which is why it would revert to the basic theme. So now the question is why doesn't DWM work when visual studio has hardware acceleration on and is maximized to 2048 x 1152